# how to set ref in list of items react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get `offsetWidth` of list Item, but my `ref.current` is **null**. Why is it?
I have created a reference and passes that reference as a props

Here is [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-chaplygin-e70ui?file=/src/App.js)

**Creating refs**

```
const tabRefs = useMemo(
    () => Array.from({ length: items.length }).map(() => createRef()),
    []
  );
```

**Setting ref as a props**

```
const getInitialProps = ({
    label,
    key,
    selected,
    childs,
    tabIndex,
    url,
    children,
    clickedTab,
    extraClass
  }) => ({
    children,
    label,
    url,
    childs,
    ref: tabRefs[key],
    originalKey: key
  });
```

Getting null `ref.current`

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tabRefs[0].current);
    // console.log(tabRefs[0].current.offsetWidth)
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

here use [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

```
const Tab = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { label } = props;
  return (
    <li {...props} ref={ref}>
      {label}
    </li>
  );
});
```

There is no `key` in your tab object.

```
<>
  <ul>
    {items.reduce((result, tab, index) => {
      result.push(<Tab {...getInitialProps({...tab, key: index})} key={index} />);
      return result;
    }, [])}
  </ul>
  <button onClick={getOffsetWidth}>get offset width</button>
</>
```

Your refs will be null on the first render, so using a useEffect is not necessary.

```
  const getOffsetWidth = () => {
    console.log(tabRefs);
  };
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-napier-ewvbg?file=/src/App.js)